# Python MongoDB aggregate and take only limited number of documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Example of my collection:

```
{
 "date": "2018-12-05 07:32:00",
 "prop_1": "some string 1",
},
{
 "date": "2018-12-06 07:32:00",
 "prop_1": "some string 2",
}
{
 "date": "2018-12-07 07:32:00",
 "prop_1": "some string 3",
}
```

An let's say i do aggregation of this collection and group by month, sum the number of items but take only limited (for this example let's say 2, any two) `prop_1` fields with `$addToSet` so that i get something like this:

```
{
  _id: "12",
  count: 3,
  prop_sample: ["some string 1", "some string 2"]
}
```

Is it possible to make aggregation work like this?

I have managed to make it work by using `forEach` but i can't use that in python.

Comment: You can use `.limit()` I think

Comment: Actually i can also use something like this in $project stage: `prop_sample: {$slice: ["$prop_sample": 2]}`, but i'm wondering is it possible to somehow limit it in $group stage